# Ruby get value from array using index

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

Given an array of letters:

```
@recipients_list = ["Mum and Dad", "my best friend", "Brother"]

# > Here are the letters available to ship, select one by number
# > 1. Mum and Dad
# > 2. My best friend
# > 3. Brother
```

As a user I then enter 3 (notice that Brother in this case is the recipient name). My code:

```
x = @recipient_list.each_with_index do |value, i|
  index_start = i + 1
  puts "#{index_start}.#{value}"
end
input = gets.chomp.to_i
puts x.at(input)
```

How to get brother value from array when user press 3? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `puts x.at(input - 1)` because of [Ruby arrays' indexing starts with 0](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html)

Comment: Funny thing is, four lines earlier they still knew that.